# How to access a particular port in managed switch?

Tags: networking, switch, port

I have serial console data; I have planned to plug the serial console cable to one of the port of managed switch. Is it possible to access only to that particular port using telnet to that switch? So that I can access serial console data without using COM port.

---

If the above stuffs are not sense. Please let me know, is there any way to get data which are coming from particular port by telnet to that particular switch?

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: yes there usually is, how about letting us know the make and model of switch - that's the very least you could do.

Comment: hp procurve 5308xl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow - very difficult to understand your question, perhaps you could re-write it? You don't mention the make or model of your switch or what you're trying to achieve.

It sounds like you're trying to connect an async serial port into an ethernet port? if that's what you're trying to do it almost certainly won't work. For managed switches there's usually a dedicated serial port and/or ethernet port - if so then use those.

Comment: If the above stuffs are not sense. Please let me know, is there any way to get data which are coming from particular port by telnet to that particular switch? model: hp procurve 5308xl

Comment: Ok then, that helps a lot, that model does have async management port but that'll only be able to use a terminal emulation mode, not Telnet, you'd need to use a regular ethernet port for telnet. If you want to use the async management port you'll need to connect to that at the right speed via a terminal emulation application, log in using the right credentials and then use either the CLI command 'show interfaces' to gain the information you need. Here's the manual; http://www.hp.com/rnd/support/manuals/3400-4200-5300-6400-ChapterFiles.htm#Config

Answer (score 0):

There's no "magic" conversion that happens when you plug a serial cable into a network port. It just won't work. To accomplish anything productive, you'll need to connect the serial cable to the console port of the switch. You'll likely be presented with either a menu or CLI-based configuration system. Depending on the capabilities of the switch, you'll be able to get per-port statistics.

Alternatively, you can look into whether or not the switch supports SNMP for retrieval of port statistics.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of for making this work is to connect your serial console to the AUX port of the switch. This may be specific to Cisco devices, where you can set up the AUX port to have "throughput" from a telnet to a specific port number (usually, I believe, TCP/2001).

If you're looking at doing this for multiple devices, you want what's usually called "a terminal server" or "a console server". There are multiple brands available, I've happily used both Cyclades and Cisco kit for this in the past (and going WAY back, the 3Com CS-200 and CS-2000, but I don't know to what extent these are available today, nearly 20 years later).